# Проблема в написании функции получения таблицы базы данных с использованием psycopg2

Tags: python, база-данных, psycopg2

Нужно написать функцию для получения данных из таблицы базы данных, чтобы функция на входе принимала название таблицы и после передать её в запрос

```
def list_db_table_content(self):
    table = dict()
    self.cur.execute("Select * FROM test")
    colnames = [desc[0] for desc in self.cur.description]
    data = (self.cur.fetchone())

    for t1, t2 in zip(colnames, data):
        table[t1] = t2
    return table
```

В строке `self.cur.execute("Select * FROM test")` вместо test(моя локальная бд и таблица в ней) нужно как-то передать разные названия таблицы. Если сделать переменной,то это уже будет строковый тип данных и выдаст ошибку. Может быть я выбрал в корни не правильный подход, или же этот код можно исправить?

Comment: А в чём именно проблема? Что мешает сделать что-то вроде self.cur.execute("Select * FROM " + table_name)